# Initiating a new blank project with expo - size on disk is 190 mb

Tags: react-native, expo

new to react native expo.
running on
node.js version 16.16.0,
npm verison 8.11.0
expo version 5.4.12 (after running npm install --global expo-cli)

when initiating a new project using

```
expo init
```

(choosing blank)
I'm getting a very large project, 190MB!
Looking into the project i see that the reason for that is node_modules,
I tried to set up the env. in 2 different PCs and getting the same thing.
for some reason i cant see any discussions on it,
can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

node_modules is always a really large folder. It has all the dependencies of your app including the expo and react native libaries. When you build your app for production your actual binary will be a fraction of that. My node_modules folder for a recent React Native app was about 1 GB but the actual app itself ended up only being about 50MB.